# elasticsearch: search with condition if array field at least one element belongs to range

Tags: search, elasticsearch, nested, nosql

I have three documents in elastic search

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "elem",
  "_id": "2",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "price": "[17,19,30]"
  }
}
```

,

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "elem",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "price": "[17,22,30]"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "elem",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "price": "[1,2,3]"
  }
}
```

When I am querying

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "range" : {
          "price" :{
            "gte":20,
            "lte":25
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response doesn't contain no one of this elements, how to query for getting exact result?** 
**I'll get** ,

```
`{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "elem",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "price": "[17,22,30]"
  }
}
```

` **in result because 22 in [20,25] range.**
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please share the mapping for this index?

Comment: `"mappings": {
"elem": {
"properties": {
"price": {
"type": "double"
}
}
}
}`

This is mapping @ArchitSaxena

Comment: I had forgotten about this question. I'm answering it anyway, even though it might be too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your documents like so:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "price": 22
    },
    {
      "price": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

and query using:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "range" : {
          "prices.price" :{
            "gte":20,
            "lte":25
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```